# $n-2$-spaces on cubic hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, cubics

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth cubic hypersurface. Is there, as in the case of $n=3$, an $n-2$-dimensional linear subspace contained in $X$? More general, is there a good description of the Picard group of $X$ for some $n\geq 4$?

Answer (score 2):

By Lefschetz theorem for $n \ge 3$ the Picard group of a smooth hypersurface is generated by the class of a hyperplane section.

Similarly, for $n \ge 5$ (again by Lefschetz theorem) the Chow group of codimension 2 cycles is generated by the class of a codimension 2 linear section; in particular a smooth hypersurface of dimension $n \ge 5$ has no codimension 2 linear subspaces.

In dimension $n = 4$ the moduli space of smooth cubic hypersurfaces (which is 20-dimensional) contains an irreducible divisor of hypersurfaces containing a plane. Thus a *general* smooth cubic 4-fold has no planes, while some *special* smooth cubic 4-folds have.

Comment: I presume you meant $n\geq 4$ and not $n\geq 3$ above.

Comment: @Mohan: Indeed, $n$ is the dimension of a hypersurface.

Comment: In the question $n$ is the dimension of the projective space, at least in the first line.

Comment: @Mohan: and in my answer $n$ is the dimension of a hypersurface. Thus it answers the question (which actually is about codimension 1 cycles) in the first paragraph, and gives more information about codimension 2 cycles in the last two.